# Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.sendStatus is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, status

I got this strange error in my application. As you can see in the `package.json` the `express` version is > `4.x`.

```
{
  "name": "MyAPI",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.6",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "pg": "^4.5.5",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^3.23.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "validator": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the source code

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var version = require('../package.json').version;
var sequelize = require('sequelize');

var userAccounts = require('../models').user_account;

router.post('/v' + version + '/register', function (res, req, next) {
    userAccounts.create(req.body).then(function () {
        next();
        return res.sendStatus(200).send({ message: ":D" });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I also tried to change the `sendStatus` to `status` but the error says the same thing about `status` too. why I am getting these errors?

Comment: It's not angular. Arguments order has mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The arguments `res` and `req` of the express handler function are in wrong order. They should be:

`function (req, res, next) {}`

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue. I didn't even notice that the order was reversed. Argh